Searching a curve with specific speed and curvature

Let $I = (a,b) \subset \Bbb{R}$ and $v: I \rightarrow (0,+\infty) , k: I \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ both differentiable. Study if there is a curve $\alpha : I \rightarrow \Bbb{R}^2$ such that $\lVert \alpha' \rVert = v $ and $\kappa_\alpha = k$ .

I am trying to do this excercise from my Differential geometry book and I want to knot if the way I am following is fine.
My idea was to use the Plane Curve's Fundamental Theorem with $l: I \rightarrow \Bbb{R}, t \mapsto \frac{k(t)}{v(t)^3}$ . This is a well defined and differentiable map since $v$ is never $0$ and both $v, k$ are differentiable. By the Theorem, there is a unique curve $\hat{\alpha} : I \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ such that $\lVert \hat{\alpha}' \rVert = 1 $ and $\kappa_{\hat{\alpha}} = l$ . Now, define somthing like $$ \alpha : I \rightarrow \Bbb{R}^2, t \rightarrow \hat{\alpha} \left( \int_a^t v(s) ds  \right)$$
My problem is that this satisfies the condition for $\lVert \alpha' \rVert$ but it does not for $\kappa_\alpha$ and I do not figure out how to fix it, so any possible help would be appreciated.

Let $t_0 \in I$ and $\theta : I \rightarrow \Bbb{R}, t \mapsto \int_{t_0}^t k(s) \cdot v(s) ds$. Define $\alpha : I \rightarrow \Bbb{R}^2, t \mapsto \int_{t_0}^t v(s) \cdot (\cos \theta (s) , \sin \theta (s) ) ds$
For each $t \in I$ :
\begin{align*} 
\alpha'(t) = v(t) \cdot (\cos \theta(t) ,\sin \theta(t)) \implies \lVert \alpha'(t)\rVert = v(t) \\
\alpha''(t) = v'(t) \cdot ( \cos \theta (t) , \sin \theta (t)) + v(t) \cdot \theta' (t) \cdot (-\sin \theta (t) , \cos \theta (t) ) \\ 
\det(\alpha'(t), \alpha''(t)) = v^2(t) \cdot \theta' (t) \\ \\
\kappa_\alpha (t) = \frac{\det(\alpha'(t), \alpha''(t))}{\lVert \alpha'(t) \rVert^3 } = \frac{v^2(t) \cdot \theta' (t)}{v^3 (t)} = \frac{v^3(t) \cdot k(t)}{v^3(t)} = k(t)
\end{align*}
so there you have a curve with your conditions.

Thanks for your answer! So it is more simple than I thought, nice to know

@Superdivinidad A pleasure, indeed you only had to adaptate the proof of the Plane Curve's Fundamental Theorem a little bit
